# Safe Riddle [Very Hard] Can't find the answer

Tags: riddle

You've been looking around for this money safe that fell off a plane for over 20 years now , You finally find it BUT :

-The safe is BULLETPROOF. 
-The safe is EXPLOSIVE IMMUNE.
-The safe is MADE FROM TITANIUM.
-The safe is HEAVILY LOCKED WITH THE LATEST LOCKING SYSTEM.
-The safe is UNHACKABLE.

The safe has :
1-The key to your future.
2-A spare key to the safe.
in it...

Comment: Is there any more context?

Comment: Well, maybe the reason you can't find the answer is that you aren't asking a question.

Comment: What is "The key to your future" and what does it do, if anything? Also, how does it have the latest locking system if it's been missing for 20 years?

Comment: This looks like you're asking us to solve a puzzle you found elsewhere.  For content that you did not create yourself, please **[provide attribution](/help/referencing)** - at minimum you need to let us know where this came from, and any additional context you can provide is usually a big help to solvers.  Posts which use someone else's content without (at minimum) disclosing where it came from are generally deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Well...

> If it was locked with the latest locking system and it fell out of a plane 20 years ago, then it must be a 20 year old locking system. If its "unhackable" but the key is inside, then its probably unhackable because its not an electronic lock. So I'd say google/YouTube instructions on how to open it. People post videos on that kind of stuff all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem did not have a clear goal that was to be achieved.
**If finding the safe was the goal - then you achieved it.**

All we know for sure is that it is a money safe with a key in it, no mention if there is actually any money inside.

**If finding the money was the goal - then there is problem.** 

Human beings sometimes fill in the missing information such as assuming the safe has money in it. This is because we possess commonsense. After spending over 20 years looking for the money, the future still remains uncertain even after finding the safe, so the next step is to move on and do other things, I guess that is the key to the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is

> Buy an identical locking system, then unlock the safe with it.

because

> The safe was locked with the latest locking mechanism 20 years ago. Assuming "the key to your future" is some sort of time travel device to my future, someone may have used it to obtain the latest locking system from my future self 20 years ago. I can buy the system, use it to take the contents of the safe, then give the system to whoever locked the safe when they use the key to my future. This assumes they do not have some other time travel method. I can ensure they got the system from me if each system has a unique serial number.